# css absolute input div position

Tags: html, css, position

I have a textbox container div (`div.tb`) with `position:relative`, containing the input and placeholder div, these both have `position:absolute`.

The problem is that the input text is vertically centered, but the placeholder text isn't vertically centered.

So I need the placeholder text to be vertically centered, just like the input.

HTML:

```
<div class="tb">
    <div class="placeholder">username</div>
    <input type="text" name="tb-username" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tb{
    position: relative;
    height: 28px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.tb input, .tb .placeholder{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 28px;
}
```

Tested with latest Chrome for Mac Os X

Thanks for your time.

Comment: And you're trying to achieve...what?

Comment: @Madbreaks vertical align, not horizontal alignment, but the input and placeholder equal centered vertically.

Comment: Try setting the line-height property of your .placeholder and make it equal to your input height.

Comment: So is the input on top of the div or vice-versa? Since they're both positioned absolutely I can't tell which one you want to show on top of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing line-height for your placeholder text. I'm not seeing what you're doing but that should fix the problem. (set a line-height equal to your input height. Hope it helps!

Comment: Do you have a link? And btw, why don't you try using the placeholder="placeholder text" inside your input tag?

Comment: because I can't style the placeholder and it won't work crossbrowser.

Comment: ok, your input height is 28px, not 18px... you can add a line-height: 28px to your .placeholder and it will work just fine! Edit: and I would use html5 placeholder anyway, and use that just as a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

if you only have to support Chrome & FF & IE 8+ then

following css will help:

```
display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;
```

also take a look at following for diff ways to achieve the same

[How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css)